# study of a function, Left continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I know it looks like an easy question not worthy of your time (and it's probably is) but can someone helps me with the study of these two functions $f,g:]0,1[\to  \mathbb R$ 
$$ 
f:x\mapsto f(x)=1-(1-x)^h
$$
with $h\in \mathbb R^+$ and 
$$
f:x\mapsto f(x)=1-k(1-x)
$$
with $k\in]0,1[$.

I know that both of these function are increasing ( "strictement croissant" in french) on their definition set but what about left continuity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to be clear here a definition of left continuity  the function f is left-continuous at the point a when $\lim f(x)=f(a)$ when $x \to a$ with $x<a$.

Comment: Those maps are continuous on their domains being the compositions of continuous maps.

Comment: thanks. So they are continuous because they are the compositions of continuous maps. A continous function is left and right continous. Therefore they are both continuous. ??

Comment: are you sure they are no problemes with their definition set

Comment: They are continuous. Therefore left and right continuous.

Comment: No issues on the interval $(0,1)$... Qui est la façon en anglais d'écrire un intervalle ouvert.

Comment: and just to be sure $f',g'>0 $ on $(0,1)$ therefore they are increasing. Thanks

Comment: That's correct. C'est exact.